# How do I connect to HP Quality Center?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, hp-quality-center

I am trying to write a program that will delete users from HP Quality Center if the username is not in the Active Directory in C#.  I have seen articles and posts saying that you should use OTA and TDAPIOLELib, these aren't available for me to reference in Visual Studio 2012.

Is there another way to access HP QC?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you gone through references like: http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/Connect-to-a-QC-project-through-the-OTA-API-using-C/td-p/4234120#.UvTftv1WFJM

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680817/how-to-connect-hp-quality-center-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net